# rowcount in flexTable in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2, flextable

I am learning GWT

In in first row of flexTable i have added combobox, combobox , text box , AddButton , Remove button.

On click event of addButton 2 row is added to the flexTable withe same component as first. ( combobox, combobox , text box , AddButton , Remove button.)

```
private Button getAddbutton() {

        addbutton = new Button("");
        addbutton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                int i = flexTable.getRowCount();
                System.out.println(" i " + i);
                i++;
                flexTable.setWidget(i, 0, getPropertyList());
                flexTable.setWidget(i, 1, getConditionList());
                flexTable.setWidget(i, 2, getKeyWord());
                flexTable.setWidget(i, 3, getAddbutton());

                flexTable.setWidget(i, 4, getRemove());
                remove.setStyleName("cmis-Button-removeOn");
                remove.setTitle(""+i);
            }
        });
        addbutton.setSize("25px", "25px");
        addbutton.setStyleName("cmis-Button-Add");

    return addbutton;
}
```

The output of i is

```
 i 1
 i 3
 i 5
 i 7
```

Why the rowCount is increasing by 2 though i have added only 4 rows in coloumn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

his is because flexTable indexing starts from 0, but you are increasing the row count. so just remove i++.